# Copy a formula from one cell, paste formula in another cell, calculate and paste special values over the formula

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I have a formula in cell `c15` that I need to copy down the entire column. However, I want to copy the formula down one cell at a time, calculate the value and then paste special values over that cell.

I want to repeat the code below to calculate one cell at a time. I can't repeat until the last cell is empty because they are all empty except cell `c15` so I'm not sure how to stop the loop.

```
Sub Macro5()
    Range("c16:c3000").Formula = Range("c15").Formula
    Range("c16:c250").Calculate
    Range("c16:c250").Value = Range("c16:c250").Value
End Sub`
```

Comment: Your code is working absolutely fine. What is wrong with your code? Based on what condition you want to stop the loop?

Comment: This code does work - that's not the problem. I need to add/adjust this code to make the process run faster. I was initially thinking I could do that by copying the formula from c15 to one cell at a time, calculating it and then pasting special values. And repeat this cell by cell so that the calculation time would be reduced. I haven't been able to figure out how to do that and then repeat all the way down the column. I want to stop the loop at row 3000.

Comment: Instead of using `Range` use `Cells(row,col)`

Comment: I've updated the code to use "cells" instead of "range".  i'm not running into the issue of the formula i'm trying to copy not updating for the new row. Like the cell references are locked in the original formula but they aren't. Here is the new code I have - any suggestions?

Sub Macro5()
    
 
     Dim i As Integer
    i = 16

    Do Until i > 25
    
    Cells(i, 3).Formula = Cells(15, 3).Formula
    
    Cells(i, 3).Calculate
    
    i = i + 1
    Loop
 
End Sub